# Get Details of Deleted Stored Procedures and Functions of DB2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, user-defined-functions

I want to get the **details of the Deleted Stored Procedures and Functions**

Also i want to get the info like when it was created & removed in DB.

Please guide me.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

You can see when procedures and functions were created by looking at the `CREATE_TIME` column tables in the system catalog like `SYSCAT.PROCEDURES` and `SYSCAT.FUNCTIONS`.

You will have no way of knowing when these objects were dropped unless you enable auditing within the database (and review the audit logs to find instances of `DROP PROCEDURE` or `DROP FUNCTION`).